# cygwin ssh works locally, not remotely

Tags: cygwin, cygwin-sshd

I have Cygwin with SSH server installed (Windows 7). After setting up I can login locally using "ssh localhost -l [myUsername]". I input my password. Success.

However, trying to SSH to the machine remotely from a different machine connects, but ALWAYS rejects the password with "permission Denied". There is no connectivity problem, obviously I'm connecting. Firewall settings are all OFF.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the following commands, after taking a backup of the files, and then restart the ssh service.

```
mkpasswd -l > /etc/passwd

mkgroup -l > /etc/group
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I spend a few hours trying to solve it. But solution is very simple. Problem lie in user name. If you login locally Windows is not case sensitive. But if you login "remotely" you have to take care of it. You must write user name exactly how it was defined in Windows.

Comment: first good answer ...

Answer (score 2):

edit `sshd_config` and ensure the following is set:

```
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
```

save the file and restart `sshd`.  This will force the `sshd` daemon to listen on all network interfaces.

Comment: no effect. still permission denied from any remote machine. and I did stop/start sshd

Comment: Shouldn't you just remove the line all together? Or is that the same thing?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you have to open port `22` through the Windows firewall of choice to make sure the port is forwarded.

Answer (score 0):

mine worked only after I used as name what is write in /etc/passwd

and it was something like *COMPUTERNAME+Administrator*

really strange that locally works without *COMPUTERNAME+*